# Using validation to prevent user from adding to the database if limit has been reached

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ajax

I'm currently trying to get some validation for my project and at the moment I'm currently stuck on preventing the user from being able to add a new amount to the database if the amount has reached it's maximum. I'm using Ajax append to display the data on the page and using a form to add more to the total quantity.

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        var url = window.location.href;
        var id = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('=') + 1);

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'http://localhost:8080/getstockitem?id=' + id,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
                if (data) {
                    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

                        console.log(data);


                        $("#itemName").append($('<p class="itemStaticText">Name: </p><p class="itemInfoText">' + data[i].stock_name + '</p>'));
                        $("#itemDescription").append($('<p class="itemStaticText">Description: </p><p class="itemInfoText itemDescriptionText">' + data[i].stock_description + '</p>'));
                        $("#itemQuantity").append($('<p class="itemStaticText">Quantity: </p><p class="itemInfoText" id="quantity">' + data[i].stock_quantity + '</p>'));
                        $("#itemShelf").append($('<p class="itemStaticText">Shelf Number: </p><p class="itemInfoText">' + data[i].shelf_number + '</p>'));
                        $("#itemRack").append($('<p class="itemStaticText">Rack Letter: </p><p class="itemInfoText">' + data[i].rack_letter + '</p>'));
                        $("#itemPrice").append($('<p class="itemStaticText">Price (£): </p><p class="itemInfoText">' + data[i].stock_price + '</p>'));

                    }
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

The code for the validation shown below:

```
function validateQuantity() {


        var quantity=document.quantityForm.quantity.value;
        var checkQuantity=document.getElementById("quanitity").value;


        if (isNaN(quantity)){
            alert("Please enter a valid number!");
            document.quantityForm.quantity.focus();
            return false;
        }else if (quantity > 1000){
            alert("Please enter a number below 1,000!");
            document.quantityForm.quantity.focus();
            return false; 
        } else if (checkQuantity > 1000) {
            alert("You have reached maximum capacity!");
            document.quantityForm.quantity.focus();
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

At the moment even if the total amount is above 1,000 it still allows the user to add more into the database, is there something I'm missing or not doing right as I'm unable to figure out how to prevent the user from adding more into the database if the maximum amount has been reached through validation.

Comment: What is the value of quantity and checkQuantity inside your validateQuantity function? Did you already check its value?

Comment: Sorry yeah I wasn't clear on the quantity which is what the user will input in the form when they add to the current amount. 
checkQuantity should be what is the current amount that is stored on the system, which is linked to the id on the appended data above.

Comment: if you input some data into the quantity field and print document.quantityForm.quantity.value, do you get the same value that you inputted?